# How to copy a variable from Matlab -workspace to Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to get the value of C in Matlab to Simulink, I could do it by using C but I want to get it as a code so not dependent on environment values. So how to get the matrix X there from Matlab to Simulink?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly your needs, the best is to define your constants in a file (.m or .mat) and call this file automatically using the `InitFcn` callback (see [doc](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/simulink/ug/using-callback-functions.html)).

Answer (score -1):

Well if you can input A and B, then it should not be hard to input C.
Try inputting the values with these rules:

- [ ] Brackets to open and close
- , Comma to seperate elements on one row
- ; Semicolon to separate two rows

Example

```
C = [ -1/3 0 0 -1/90 0.0037; 6 7 8 9 10; 11 12 13 14 15]
```

Comment: Did I get a downvote because it does not function, or because it is inconvenient for large matrices?